# Convert a string to Upper case using custom attributes in C#

Tags: c#, string, attributes

I am trying to create a custom attribute which could convert any string property in my class to upper case by using the attributes.

Something like below:

```
 public class MyStringAttribute : Attribute
 {
    private string Value { get; set; }

    public MyStringAttribute (string value)
    {
        this.Value = value.Trim().ToUpper();
    }
}
```

But I couldn't make it work with my code. Wondering if there is any help I could get in making this work.

I am using the attribute in my class as below:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [MyStringAttribute] // How do I pass MyString and convert to Uppercase here?
    public string MyString { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: "I couldn't make it work" is not specific enough of a problem. Why doesn't it work with your code? Is there an error message? What are you expecting to happen? Please edit your question to include these things.

Comment: This is an XY problem. Attributes are not the solution. Attributes don't affect the code elements to which they're applied without some other code to make it happen. They're purely informational. If you want the property to automatically be forced to uppercase, the setter would have to look for the attribute applied to it to determine it should do that (which obviates the attribute, really). If you want something else to see the value as uppercase, that thing would have to recognize that the attribute is applied to the property and convert the value after getting it.

Comment: There are certain pseudo-attributes that *do* affect code elements. For example, `[Serializable]` actually applies the IL `serializable` modifier to the class. The attribute itself is not in the attribute metadata. No attribute you can define would behave this way, though.

Comment: Finally, an attribute instance knows nothing about the code element to which it's applied, nor any instance of the type, so you couldn't possibly affect the value (not without retrieving the attribute, calling one of its methods, and passing it an instance, that is). So to address the XY problem, what were you originally trying to do?

Comment: Regarding your edit, I invite you to re-read my comments. Attributes cannot do what you're asking them to do. Some other code has to find the attribute and understand what it means, and then do that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am new to writing custom attributes and updated my original problem on the usage of the attribute in my class.

Comment: @madreflection - Thank you. If i use the setter, then i need to have the same logic for every setter property in my classes. I was trying if there is a way to make this generic so i can use in my class and convert them to case specific.

Comment: That's correct. You could use code weaving/AOP to do this, but it's not part of the compiler itself. It is, as I've described, some piece of code that looks at the attribute, understands what it means, and behaves accordingly which, in that case, involves modifying the IL to include the new behavior.